# Multiply root filesystems? In Linux?

Tags: linux, vfs

I use Linux for a while, now. I always thought that there is only one rootfs in Linux. However, I recently read that PipeFS is mounted in "pipe:", in its own root.

How is this possible. Are they separate instances of VFS, or is it just one of its features to manage multiple roots?

Comment: This question has been posted on multiple sites. Cross-posting is strongly discouraged; see the help center and [community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) for more information. By the way, can you link to the assertion?

Comment: The other question on [SO]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489522/multiply-root-filesystems-in-linux